# First playbook, keep getting an error on YAML - Name

Tags: ansible

I'm a bit out of my wheelhouse here. Normally i code only in Powershell.

I was asked to use AWX/Ansible to automate the creation of user centric AD groups.
I did a lot of reading, figured out how to set up an inventory/project/template/survey/import hosts/credentials/ ... .

But what i can't seem to figure out, is this YAML.
According to most information i've found, it seems to be best to use an indentation of 2 spaces, no tabs.
So i did. But i keep getting the following error :

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key
The error appears to be in '.../CreateUserCentricGroups.yml': line 27, column 3, ...
The offending line appears to be:
  - name: Setup variables
  ^ here
```

This is the YAML. It was bigger but i made it into the most basic i could think of, in order to find the error. Still, at the first action it fails.

```
---
- name: Create user centric AD-groups
  hosts: "{{ domainName }}"
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    GroupNameUpper: "RCWR_UC_APP_{{ appName | upper }}"
    groupDescription: "{{ appDescription }}"
    domainDict:
      "Labo": "DC=whatever"
    domainDC: '{{domainDict[domainName | default("Labo")] | default("stop") }}' #Allow for future domains to be used.
    companyDC: "whatever"
  tasks:
  - name: Do something with the variables, print full groupname.
    debug:
      msg: "{{ GroupNameUpper }}"

  - name: Verify if the group already exists in AD #Error occurs here <-
    register: lookupResult
    win_shell: |
      Try {
        $user = Get-ADGroup {{ GroupNameUpper }}
        echo "Group {{ GroupNameUpper }} already exists."
      }
      catch {
          echo "Group {{ GroupNameUpper }} does not exist yet."
      }
      Try {
        $user = Get-ADGroup "{{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt"
        echo "Group {{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt already exists."
      }
      catch {
          echo "Group {{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt does not exist yet."
      }
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookupResult }}"
    #gather_facts: false

  - name: Inform that group already exists
    debug:
        msg: Group {{ GroupNameUpper }} already exists in {{ domainName }}.
    meta: end_play #https://medium.com/opsops/finishing-playbook-on-condition-in-ansible-958b81d3476d THIS SHOULD STOP IF 1 OF THE 2 GROUPS EXIST.
    when: "'already exists' in lookupResult.stdout"

  - name: Create groups in AD
    register: createOutput
    win_shell: |
        Try {
          $SamAccountname = "{{ GroupNameUpper }}" -replace "_","" -replace "RCWRUC",""
          New-ADUser -Name "{{ GroupNameUpper }}" -DisplayName "{{ GroupNameUpper }}" -SamAccountName $SamAccountName -Description "{{ groupDescription }}" -GroupCategory "Security" -GroupScope "DomainLocal" -Path "OU=Groups,{{ companyDC }},OU=Departments,{{ domainDC }},DC=com"
        }
        catch {
            echo "Group {{ GroupNameUpper }} creation failed."
        }
        Try {
          $SamAccountname = "{{ GroupNameUpper }}" -replace "_","" -replace "RCWRUC",""
          New-ADUser -Name "{{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt" -DisplayName "{{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt" -SamAccountName $SamAccountName -Description "{{ groupDescription }}" -GroupCategory "Security" -GroupScope "DomainLocal" -Path "OU=Groups,{{ companyDC }},OU=Departments,{{ domainDC }},DC=com"
        }
        catch {
            echo "Group {{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt creation failed."
        }        
    when: "'does not exist yet' in lookupResult.stdout"
    failed_when: "('creation failed' in createOutput.stdout) or (createOutput.rc != 0)"
    no_log: true

  - name: Determine email address (Jenkins)
    set_fact:
      sendToEmailAddress: "{{ requestorMail }}"
    when: requestorMail is defined

  - name: Determine email address (non-Jenkins)
    set_fact:
      sendToEmailAddress: "{{ awx_user_email }}"
    when: requestorMail is not defined

  - name: Communicate result
    delegate_to: localhost
    mail:
          subject: "Create AD-group {{ GroupNameUpper }}"
          body:  "Groups {{ GroupNameUpper }} have been created in {{ domainName }}"
          host: "exchangeserver"
          port: 25 
          to: "{{sendToEmailAddress}}"
          from: "noreply@us.com"
          secure: starttls
          subtype: html
    when: "'does not exist yet' in lookupResult.stdout"  
    no_log: true 
...
```

What am i forgetting or doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time/help.

Comment: where the variable {{ domainName }} was declared ?

Comment: It can be changed as a value in the survey but it is also defined in the template YAML.
domainName: labo

Comment: Typically we define tasks with Ansible [modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/modules_by_category.html) under `tasks:` section of playbook. `vars:` is a separate section, and `gather_facts:` parameter is for the `hosts:` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the exact error you listed, but your play is kind of play-shaped but not valid.

Your task is not a valid task, since it contains a play-level directive (`gather_facts`) and does not contain a valid action name.

Assuming you want these variables to apply to the entire play, this is a more valid (and more consistently formatted) reworking of the limited example you provided:

```yaml
- name: Create user centric AD-groups
  hosts: "{{ domainName }}"
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    GroupNameUpper: Prefix1_APP_{{ appName | upper }}
    groupDescription: "{{ appDescription }}"
    domainDict:
      Labo: DC=whatever
    domainDC: "{{ domainDict[domainName | default('Labo')] | default('stop') }}"
    companyDC: Whatever
  tasks:
    - name: Do something with the variables
      debug:
        msg: "{{ domainDC }}"
```

Comment: First of all, a very big thank you for helping me out.
I applied your logic to my file but i still ran into an issue as soon as it starts the second task. I will create a new post with the full script in (obfuscated a little bit but not very much).

Comment: So i've found out that i need to split things up more. I need to make a separate task for showing the output with debug. I'm learning ...